# C++ Qt - Get Physical Disk Size (Win32)

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, hard-drive

How can I get the physical size of all hard disks on the current computer using C++ / Qt framework on Windows? Just to be clear, if I have a 640 GB HDD, I want to the application to show 640 GB, not 596 GB of available space.

I know that Qt probably doesn't have a function I could use, because it has to be platform-specific, so I guess in this case something from the Win32 API. Unfortunately I can't use GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(), because I would only get the free/available disk space. I've read about using WMI, but I can't seem to find any usable code examples for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue is mainly cosmetic as a result of inconsistencies in measurements used by Operating Systems and Hard Drive manufacturers. Check [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte#Definition) for more information. Perhaps find a way to do the math while treating 1 Kilobyte as 1000 bytes (instead of 1024), 1 Megabyte as 1000 * 1000 and so on -- instead of 1 kilobyte as 1024 bytes etc.

Comment: It seems I don't understand what are you trying to say. How can this help me in coming up with a function I can use to get physical disk size? Bear in mind, I'm a beginner in C++ programming, and I believe there must be something already made for this purpose.

Comment: Forget my last comment, you actually gave me the idea how to calculate the declared HDD capacity from the space available to the user. I used GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() to get totalNumberOfBytes, and then simply calculated hddPhysicalSize in GB with (totalNumberOfBytes * 1073741824) / 1000000000.

Comment: @Marko exactly what I was trying to say :) I'm glad it worked out for you.